# why Semi-Automatic Classification plugin installation failled repeatedly?

Tags: qgis-plugins

I successfully downloaded Semi-Automatic Classification plugin installer OSGEO from http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/osgeo4w-setup.exe. But it respond that it couldn't the installation.
Again I download manually from  http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml and when I extract it in plugins folder still QGIS window respond that I commit error. how can I instal it?

Answer (score 2):

For this plugin, the installation is special (there are others things to install). For windows, see [Install the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin in QGIS: a Windows guide](http://fromgistors.blogspot.be/2013/06/install-Semiautomatic-Plugin-Windows.html)

After that you can install the plugin in the traditional way:

1. Select Fetch Python Plugins under the Plugins menu of QGIS;
2. Install the SEXTANTE plugin and then the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin;
3. configure SEXTANTE, etc., see [Configuration of the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin](http://fromgistors.blogspot.be/2013/06/configuration-of-semi-automatic.html)